Bounding the error of a truncated moment problem
Let $\{x_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a non-increasing sequence of non-negative real numbers, and let $\{y_{j}\}_{j=1}^{B}$ be a non-increasing sequence of non-negative real numbers, where $B$ is a finite integer.
For each integer $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, define the $k$-th moment of the sequences as
$$
m_{x}(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i}^{k}, \quad m_{y}(k) = \sum_{j=1}^{B} y_{j}^{k}.
$$
Suppose that for each $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$,
$$
m_{x}(k) = m_{y}(k).
$$
Define the measure of difference $L$ between the sequences as
$$
L = \sum_{j=1}^{B} \left| x_{j} - y_{j} \right|.
$$
Under the above conditions, what would be the upper bound on $L$ in terms of $\{x_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, $B$, and $n$?

In the definition of $m_x(k)$, should $B$ be the upper limit on the summation instead of $\infty$?
